# Como fazer um espaço amostral utilizando dados de 4,6 e 8 lados?

Tags: python

Estou fazendo um trabalho de probabilidade de espaço amostral de 3 dados (um de 4 lados, um de 6 lados e outros de 8 lados)
Eu sei que o espaço amostral, sem repetição entre os dados, é de 4*6*8 = 192.
Eu vi num topico aqui o seguinte script:

```
from itertools import product

caracteres = [0, 1, 2]
permsList = []
genComb = product(caracteres, repeat=2) # aqui e onde tens de especificar o numero de chars que cada combinacao tenha
for subset in genComb:
    print(subset) # tuple retornado com uma combinacao por loop
    permsList.append(subset)
print(permsList) # [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

Onde o comando product gera todas as combinações possíveis, incluindo caracteres repetidos

Porém, faltou somente duas coisas:

1. as combinações possiveis nao ser repetidas
2. que os dados fossem de 1 até as respectivas faces.

Como por exemplo:

```
[(4,6,8); (3,6,8) ; (4,5,8) ; (4,6,7) ; (2,6,8) ; . . . ]
```

Alguem poderia me ajudar?

**Edit (solucionado)**
Fiz um scrip, com a ajuda dos envolvidos aqui, e pode-se fazer um espaço amostral para quantos dados quiser, até 5, com quantas faces desejadas em cada:

```
from itertools import product

if(A==1 or A==2 or A==3 or A==4 or A==5):
    if(A==1):
        a=input("Quantas faces possui o dado 1?: ")

        print(list(product(range(1, a+1))))

    if(A==2):
        a=int(input("Quantas faces possui o dado 1?: "))
        b=int(input("Quantas faces possui o dado 2?: "))

        print(list(product(range(1, a+1), range(1, b+1))))

    if(A==3):
        a=int(input("Quantas faces possui o dado 1?: "))
        b=int(input("Quantas faces possui o dado 2?: "))
        c=int(input("Quantas faces possui o dado 3?: "))

        print(list(product(range(1, a+1), range(1, b+1), range(1, c+1))))

    if(A==4):
        a=int(input("Quantas faces possui o dado 1?: "))
        b=int(input("Quantas faces possui o dado 2?: "))
        c=int(input("Quantas faces possui o dado 3?: "))
        d=int(input("Quantas faces possui o dado 4?: "))

        print(list(product(range(1, a+1), range(1, b+1), range(1, c+1), range(1, d+1))))

    if(A==5):
        a=int(input("Quantas faces possui o dado 1?: "))
        b=int(input("Quantas faces possui o dado 2?: "))
        c=int(input("Quantas faces possui o dado 3?: "))
        d=int(input("Quantas faces possui o dado 4?: "))
        e=int(input("Quantas faces possui o dado 5?: "))

        print(list(product(range(1, a+1), range(1, b+1), range(1, c+1), range(1, d+1), range(1, e+1))))


else:
    print("Utilize números inteiros de 1 a 5")
```

**Para caso queira saber o evento:**

```
from itertools import product

A=int(input("Quantas dados serão utilizados? (1-5): "))


if(A==1 or A==2 or A==3 or A==4 or A==5):
    if(A==1):
        a=input("Quantas faces possui o dado 1?: ")
        X=input("Qual o evento (soma do número de faces)?: ")

        resultado = product(range(1, a+1))
        somam = [ x for x in resultado if x[0] == X]
        print("Os eventos são, para os dados de :")
        print(somam)


    if(A==2):
        a=int(input("Quantas faces possui o dado 1?: "))
        b=int(input("Quantas faces possui o dado 2?: "))
        X=input("Qual o evento (soma do número de faces)?: ")

        resultado = product(range(1, a+1), range(1,b+1))
        somam = [ x for x in resultado if x[0] + x[1] == X]
        print("Os eventos são, para os dados de :")
        print(somam)

    if(A==3):
        a=int(input("Quantas faces possui o dado 1?: "))
        b=int(input("Quantas faces possui o dado 2?: "))
        c=int(input("Quantas faces possui o dado 3?: "))
        X=input("Qual o evento (soma do número de faces)?: ")

        resultado = product(range(1, a+1), range(1,b+1), range(1,c+1))
        somam = [ x for x in resultado if x[0] + x[1] + x[2] == X]
        print("Os eventos são, para os dados de :")
        print(somam)


    if(A==4):
        a=int(input("Quantas faces possui o dado 1?: "))
        b=int(input("Quantas faces possui o dado 2?: "))
        c=int(input("Quantas faces possui o dado 3?: "))
        d=int(input("Quantas faces possui o dado 4?: "))
        X=input("Qual o evento (soma do número de faces)?: ")

        resultado = product(range(1, a+1), range(1,b+1), range(1,c+1), range(1,d+1))
        somam = [ x for x in resultado if x[0] + x[1] + x[2] + x[3] == X]
        print("Os eventos são, para os dados de :")
        print(somam)

    if(A==5):
        a=int(input("Quantas faces possui o dado 1?: "))
        b=int(input("Quantas faces possui o dado 2?: "))
        c=int(input("Quantas faces possui o dado 3?: "))
        d=int(input("Quantas faces possui o dado 4?: "))
        e=int(input("Quantas faces possui o dado 5?: "))
        X=input("Qual o evento (soma do número de faces)?: ")

        resultado = product(range(1, a+1), range(1,b+1), range(1,c+1), range(1,d+1), range(1,e+1))
        somam = [ x for x in resultado if x[0] + x[1] + x[2] + x[3] + x[4] == X]
        print("Os eventos são, para os dados de :")
        print(somam)
else:
    print("Utilize números inteiros de 1 a 5")
```

Comment: Vamos deixar isso mais claro: o dado de quatro lados possui os lados `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, o de seis possui `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` e o de oito possui `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`, correto? Você quer gerar todas as combinações em que o valor dos lados não se repita? Por exemplo, a saída deve conter `[1, 2, 3]`, mas não pode conter `[1, 2, 1]`, é isso?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss além da repetição de valores, é preciso saber se a ordem importa, ex. se [1, 2, 3] == [3, 2, 1] será considerado `True` ou não

Comment: @Blogueira muito bem observado. Aproveitando, eu calculei aqui e 192 é o número de sequências **com** repetição. Sem repetição, como solicitado, possui apenas 120 sequências.

Comment: Eu devo ter me expressado errado.
É assim: o espaço amostral todo é 192, com as não repetições é sendo, por exemplo, [(4,6,8); (3,6,8) ; (4,5,8) ; (4,6,8);  (4,5,8); . . . ], é não repetindo valores anteriores.
Os valores obtidos podem ser [(1,1,1); (1,1,2); (1,2,1); (1,3,2); ... ] indefinidamente, somente que a ordem sejam prevalecidas, ou seja, desta forma:
considerando a, b e c pertencentes aos inteiros positivos somente, têm-se a seguinte ordem [(a,b,c)],   não podendo ser [(b,a,c)], ou seja, nao mudando de ordem

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, é que eu quero as combinações possíveis no lançamento desses três dados, ou seja o espaço amostral.
Respodendo a sua pergunta, a ordem nao importa, pelo seu exemplo,  [1, 2, 3] é diferente de [3, 2, 1], seriam duas combinações possiveis aqui
No caso do meu comentario anterior, 'a' assumiria valores entre 1 a 4 (dado de 4 lados), 'b' asumiria valores de 1 a 6 (dados de 6 lados) e 'c' assumiria valores de 1 a 8 lados (dado de 8 lados)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se o que você busca é obter a combinação dos resultados dos três dados (todas as 192), um simples `for loop` bastaria:

```
lista = []
for i in range(1, 5):
    for j in range(1, 7):
        for k in range(1, 9):
            lista.append((i, j, k))
```

Ou, usando o `itertools` como no seu exemplo:

```
from itertools import product
list(product(range(1, 5), range(1, 7), range(1, 9)))
```

Em ambos os exemplos, o resultado é o seguinte:

```
[(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 3), (1, 1, 4), (1, 1, 5), (1, 1, 6),
 (1, 1, 7), (1, 1, 8), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4),
 (1, 2, 5), (1, 2, 6), (1, 2, 7), (1, 2, 8), (1, 3, 1), (1, 3, 2),
 (1, 3, 3), (1, 3, 4), (1, 3, 5), (1, 3, 6), (1, 3, 7), (1, 3, 8),
 (1, 4, 1), (1, 4, 2) ... (4, 6, 7), (4, 6, 8)]
```

---

#### Edit:

Para listar apenas as combinações cuja soma de elementos é igual a 13, você pode iterar pelo resultado, testando item a item:

```
somam_treze = []
resultado = product(range(1, 5), range(1, 7), range(1, 9))
for x in resultado:
    if (x[0] + x[1] + x[2] == 13):
        somam_treze.append(x)
```

Ou:

```
somam_treze = [ x for x in resultado if x[0] + x[1] + x[2] == 13]
```

Resultado:

```
>>> somam_treze
[(1, 4, 8), (1, 5, 7), (1, 6, 6), (2, 3, 8), (2, 4, 7), (2, 5, 6), (2, 6, 5), (3, 2, 8), (3, 3, 7), (3, 4, 6), (3, 5, 5), (3, 6, 4), (4, 1, 8), (4, 2, 7), (4, 3, 6), (4, 4, 5), (4, 5, 4), (4, 6, 3)]
```

Peguei esses códigos *emprestados* [daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935194/combinations-between-two-lists) e [daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33553046/storing-values-from-loop-in-a-list-or-tuple-in-python).

Comment: Só lembrando que a função `product` retorna um *generator*, então se não for necessário acessar a lista completa, é melhor mantê-la como *generator* e iterar sobre o mesmo.

Comment: Muito obrigado @Blogueira, era isso mesmo que eu estava procurando, passei horas procurando ontem e anteontem e nao encontrei em nenhum lugar falando sobre isso, nem mesmo utilizando dois dados simples de 6 lados como conhecemos \
Se nao for pedir muito, é possivel, utilizando este mesmo espaço amostral de 192 combinações, fazer ele somente dar os resultados referentes a um certo numero? \
Por exemplo: sendo uma ordem qualquer [(a,b,c)], eu quero todos as ordens possiveis que resulte em 13, por exemplo, assim, a+b+c = 13 entao teremos como resultados [(4,6,3); (4,5,4), (1,6,6), (5,5,3), ..

Comment: @LuisCarlosMoura adicionei informações - veja 'edit' no final da resposta!

Comment: Nao sei como te agradecer @Blogueira
Muito obrigado mesmo

Comment: @Blogueira, como deu para perceber, eu sou bem iniciante em programaçao, e estou tendo um pequeno problema em compilar o script
Eu uso Python com interface Spyder e estou utilizando estas linhas:
somam_treze = []
resultado = product(range(1, 5), range(1, 7), range(1, 9))
for x in resultado:
    if (x[0] + x[1] + x[2] == 13):
        print(somam_treze.append(x))
Só que ao responder, ele me da isso:
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None

Comment: Use o segundo exemplo: somam_treze = `[ x for x in resultado if x[0] + x[1] + x[2] == 13]` - depois em outra linha, escreva `print(somam_treze)`.